Module 'Typing' not found when compiling Python 3.12 from source
On a Raspberry Pi 4, I am trying to update Python from 3.7.3 to 3.12 in order to use async for the bleak library. I understand that the only way to do this on an RPi is to compile Python from source. I followed the steps that led to a successful install. However, when I tried to install a package using pip, I got the following: WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
I discovered that I need to recompile Python 3.12 with ssl enabled. Looking through the Modules/Setup file, I found this:
# NOTE: Avoid editing this file directly. Local changes should go into
# Modules/Setup.local file. To enable all modules for testing, run
#
#    sed -n -E 's/^#([a-z_\*].*)$/\1/p' Modules/Setup > Modules/Setup.local

So I ran the sed command. Then I ran ./configure. Then I ran make. However, I get an error:
./_bootstrap_python ./Tools/build/deepfreeze.py \
Python/frozen_modules/importlib._bootstrap.h:importlib._bootstrap \
Python/frozen_modules/importlib._bootstrap_external.h:importlib._bootstrap_external \
Python/frozen_modules/zipimport.h:zipimport \
Python/frozen_modules/abc.h:abc \
Python/frozen_modules/codecs.h:codecs \
Python/frozen_modules/io.h:io \
Python/frozen_modules/_collections_abc.h:_collections_abc \
Python/frozen_modules/_sitebuiltins.h:_sitebuiltins \
Python/frozen_modules/genericpath.h:genericpath \
Python/frozen_modules/ntpath.h:ntpath \
Python/frozen_modules/posixpath.h:posixpath \
Python/frozen_modules/os.h:os \
Python/frozen_modules/site.h:site \
Python/frozen_modules/stat.h:stat \
Python/frozen_modules/importlib.util.h:importlib.util \
Python/frozen_modules/importlib.machinery.h:importlib.machinery \
Python/frozen_modules/runpy.h:runpy \
Python/frozen_modules/__hello__.h:__hello__ \
Python/frozen_modules/__phello__.h:__phello__ \
Python/frozen_modules/__phello__.ham.h:__phello__.ham \
Python/frozen_modules/__phello__.ham.eggs.h:__phello__.ham.eggs \
Python/frozen_modules/__phello__.spam.h:__phello__.spam \
Python/frozen_modules/frozen_only.h:frozen_only \
-o Python/deepfreeze/deepfreeze.c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/lib/python3.12.2/Python-3.12.2/./Tools/build/deepfreeze.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Dict, FrozenSet, TextIO, Tuple
  File "/home/pi/lib/python3.12.2/Python-3.12.2/Lib/typing.py", line 36, in <module>
    from _typing import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_typing'
make: *** [Makefile:1407: Python/deepfreeze/deepfreeze.c] Error 1

It appears that I am missing the module Typing. How do I install the module Typing without using pip? Is this a Catch-22 situation?
How do I get around this error?

"To enable all modules for testing..." are you testing? Do you really want to enable all modules?

_typing is a relatively new addition to CPython (Modules/_typingmodule.c first appears in 2021, so that would be new to, what, Python 3.10?) You might be able to upgrade to Python 3.10 first, then try to build Python 3.12.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to determine which modules I need. I do know that I need ssl in order to use pip. Isn't Python without pip practically useless? Why wouldn't that be included by default?

Note that _typing isn't something you would install via pip; it's an implementation detail of the typing module (its sole purpose is to speed up calls to typing.NewCall).

pip is a third-party tool for installing third-party packages. Python ships with ensurepip which can install a (vendored) version of pip that's packaged with Python. pip can then upgrade itself.

(bootstrap_python is used to 'run
"Tools/build/deepfreeze.py" on systems with no or older Python
interpreter.' It's possible that something as old as Python 3.7 is worse than no version of Python at all.)

Yeah, sorry to bother you gents. It turns out that I had upgraded to Python 3.12, not because of bleak, but because of something else that I was planning to use. I'll let the world keep banging its head on upgrading Python on RPi, and revisit when there is a better understanding. For now, I have punted back to Python 3.7.3 that came stock on the RPi. Va multsumesc!
